# My kid dropped my cigarette lighter inside the car AC window

Tags: ac

My kid dropped the cigarette lighter inside the car AC window. It's a 2006 Ford Fiesta. Is it okay to drive? Or do I need to immediately take it to the garage?

Comment: Do you mean the AC vent, where the hot/cold air blows from in the cabin?

Comment: How did your child fit the lighter through the AC vent? Can you edit and add a picture of the opening?

Comment: You may be able to "fish" it out using a magnet on a string.  It might be worth trying before you spend money on a repair shop.  I would say it's safe to drive.

Comment: Why in the world is this tagged [tag:manual-transmission]? Why is your kid playing with a lighter?